# How to change suffixIcon to custom icon in text field in flutter

Tags: flutter

My requirement is need to use some different icon in place of suffixIcon in flutter but using suffixIcon there are in build icons like :

```
suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        //eye icon
                        color: Color(0xFF919191),
                        onPressed: () {
                          //for keyboard to hide
                          FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
                          if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                            currentFocus.unfocus();
                          }
                          //for keyboard to hide
                          setState(() {
                            isHidePassword = !isHidePassword;
                          });
                        },
                        icon: Icon(isHidePassword
                            ? Icons.visibility
                            : Icons.visibility_off)),,
```

How to use custom icon instead of visibility & visibility_off in suffixIcon in text field in flutter.

Attaching image for more understanding what i have tried using suffic icon is as below [image]

what i need to achieve is [image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Use outlined Icon data for it.

Replace  `Icons.visibility` with  `Icons.visibility_outlined` and

`Icons.visibility_off` with `Icons.visibility_off_outlined,`

```dart
icon: Icon(
  isHidePassword
      ? Icons.visibility_outlined
      : Icons.visibility_off_outlined,
),
```

check [visibility_outlined-constant](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons/visibility_outlined-constant.html)

Comment: how to add tint color for Icons.visibility_off with Icons.visibility_off_outlined?

Comment: Color of icons? there is a `color` parameter on `Icon` can be use.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code hope its help to you.

declare bool variable:

```
bool obsecureText = true;
```

Hide/Unhide Password function

```
 void showPassword() {
    setState(() {
      obsecureText = !obsecureText;
    });
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
 TextFormField(
        obscureText: obsecureText,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            onPressed: showPassword,
            icon: Icon(
              obsecureText ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
            ),
          ),
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.vpn_key,
          ),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Password',
          hintText: 'Enter Password Here',
        ),
      ),
```

Your result screen hide password -> [image]

Your result screen display password-> [image]